# rich snippets for div class

Tags: rich-snippets

If I have a div class ie : `<div class="wrap">content</div><div class="definition"></div>` 
how do you include rich snippets. I understand that it should be `<div itemscope ect.` but what if you have a name for that class and not a single

Comment: The correct term for this is microdata. But I can't understand what do you mean with "but what if you have a name for that class and not a single "

Comment: if you have "wrap" and "definition" in the div strucutre

Comment: The schema.org or data-vocabulary.org whichever microdata definitions will not disturb webpage display. Try wrapping the microdata (richsnippet) specific <div>s around your web page construction <div>s.  Please test your code snippet using http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets (Structured Data Testing Tool) for better understanding.